How does Binance allocate Margin to Cross mode position?
I'm trying to get my head around the values shown in Binance's Futures position, and how they're related to one another. I'm puzzled about the Margin column in the Positions view.
It appears as if the Margin there was simply position size / leverage. Indeed, the allocated Margin value decreases as the position size gets smaller. But that's counterintuitive in a long position - I would expect the allocated margin to increase as my position loses on value, if anything!
My question is threefold:

how is this column computed?
what does it indicate?
what does it have an impact on?



Have you asked Binance support?
